# Mongodb shell drop collections with wild card

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongo-collection

I have a bunch of collections with the same prefix e.g. data_user_1, data_user_2 etc.
There are also a few collection in between that I wanted to keep and skip from dropping.

So I search for a solution to

a) drop all exclude specific
b) drop all data_user_*

I searched the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/#db.collection.drop) but there seems to be no parameter that allows any of these operations.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such option.

1. You can retrieve all the available collections using [getCollectionNames](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/)
2. Then you can check for include/exclude scenarios.
3. When the condition matches, you can perform `drop` on it.

Comment: Thank you. I posted the solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

I give up searching as there seems to be no "comfortable" way. So I have written a short script which fullfills the requirement (and is also pretty comfortable^^).

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname){
if(collname.includes('data_user')){ 
 print('delete collection: ' + collname); 
 db.getCollection(collname).drop()}
});
```

Hope this helps someone else too.